# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps not showing in VS code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have a `.eslintrc` file with the following rules:

```
"rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error",
    "no-console": "warn"
},
```

I've installed: `eslint-plugin-prettier`, `eslint-config-prettier` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`

I've enabled `"eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "javascriptreact", "html", "typescriptreact" ],` in settings.json in vscode

but when I remove dependencies that are needed in a `useEffect`, it's not showing an error that I hoped it would

what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 6):

I use react 18.2.0 , react-scripts 5.0.1 and react-app-rewired 2.2.1.
You must to add some code in `.eslintrc`.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    // ...
    "react-hooks" // for activate eslint checking react hooks
  ],
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `.eslintrc`, along with to adding `rules`, you must add `react-hooks` in the list of `plugins`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    // ...
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry I should have added this. I already have this. do I need to be on CRA/react scripts version 4+?

Comment: @RedBaron according to [CRA doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor), it is said that *this feature is available with react-scripts@0.2.0 and higher*. did you try to run `eslint` command manually in the terminal to check if there was the expected error?

Comment: there is a definite change between react-scripts 3.x.x and 4.x.x. when I install 3 and restart ESLint server it disappears. when I install and restart, it's there

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me only when I updated `react-scripts` to `4.x.x`

It also helps to restart the ESLint server in VScode after doing this

`hgb123` answer also is useful if you haven't already done that